# Is there any way to check whether there is an incoming message in Python Socket

Tags: python, sockets

I am using a socket in Python and trying to find out how to check whether there is an incoming message in the code. I need it to print if there is an incoming message. If there is not an incoming message, just will write 'NO DATA'

I have tried to check with an if condition but it did not work:

```
import socket
import time
#AG AYARLARI
HOST = ''
PORT = 16000
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST,PORT))

#AGI BASLATMA


s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
i=0
print('I:::',i)
print('Connected by', addr)
 while True:
        data=conn.recv(1024)
        if data:
            print(data)
        else:
            print (str.encode('No data'))
            break
```

- If there is a message take: "Message"
- If not: "No Data"

Comment: Where is `conn` defined?

Comment: Is `conn` an object of the class `socket.socket`? If so, it is configured as "blocking" by default. This means the interpreter will wait until a message is received. You simply check here, wether `data` is empty or not.

Comment: You do not want that. If you require that the data is present immediately, you have a race condition, because you could try to get it before the sender could provide it. So you will at least need a timeout. In that case the answer is *use `select`*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `select`:

```
    import select

    timeout = 10  # in seconds
    ready_sockets, _, _ = select.select(
        [conn], [], [], timeout
    )
    if ready_sockets:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        print(data)
    else:
        print('No data')
```

Read more about it here: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/select.html